# take only part of word or number from a sentence in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this text `My Quote (2 items)` now with jquery, i have to take only `2`.
How can i get two from this given value.

```
var data['count'] = 'My Quote(2 items)'
```

Now, what i'm trying to get is

```
var data['count'] = 2
```

**Note** : 
As it's a quote count. it can be 'My Quote(2 items)' or 'My Quote(20 items)'

Comment: You need to provide more sample inputs. As it stands, you can use `var data['count'] = 2` to get the value `2` and put it in your variable. The easiest way of getting a value based on one possible input: hardcode the value.

Comment: You can use regex, but we need more details about the logic. Do you only want to take the first integer found? The first character within brackets? Something else...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as it's a quote count it can be like `2 items` or `10 items`

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str = 'My Quote(2 items)';
alert(str.match(/\d+/g) + " items");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery isn't used for a simple `match` you can delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I comment the code ;-)

For a "visual description" of the regex you can view it on [regexplain](http://tinyurl.com/l6wx5xm)

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  // generate quotes...
  var str = 'My Quote(' + i + ' items)';
  
  // extract the number by a regex
  // match a parentheses \(
  // match at least 1 number (\d+) and put it in $1
  // followed by the text ' item'
  // extract the $1
  var extract = str.match(/\((\d+) item/)[1];

  document.write(str + ' : ' + extract + '<br />');
}
```